# Make comma separated column from multiple lines

Tags: bash, csv, impala

I have the following set-up

```
ITEM1   a
ITEM1   b
ITEM1   c
ITEM2   bla
ITEM2   ds
```

and I would like to turn it into the following in a simple statement (like STUFF in SQL)

```
ITEM1   a,b,c
ITEM2   bla,ds
```

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Did you find any answer useful?

Answer (score 2):

Pure Bash (requires Bash 4.0 or greater for associative arrays):

```
#!/bin/bash

# Associative array for aggregated lines
declare -A lines

# Append second column value to value of first column key
while read -r key value; do
    lines[$key]+="$value,"
done < "$1"

for key in "${!lines[@]}"; do    
    # Print key and comma separated values (last comma removed)
    printf "%s\t%s\n" "$key" "${lines[$key]%,}"
done
```

This collects, for each value of the first column, the values of the second column in a comma separated string.

The second loop then takes each key, removes the comma from the end of that line and prints the key and the comma separated values.

For the example input, we get

```
$ ./SO.sh infile 
ITEM2   bla,ds
ITEM1   a,b,c
```

Note that the order of the keys is non-deterministic.

Answer (score 0):

maybe is not the best one, but is a starting point

```
#!/bin/bash


FILE="input2.txt"

for item in $(cut -d" " -f1 $FILE | sort|uniq)
do
        printf "%s\t" $item
        grep $item $FILE | awk '{printf "%s"  $2","}'| sed "s/,$//g"
        printf "\n"
done
```

I've used this file `input2.txt` as input:

```
ITEM1   a
ITEM1   b
ITEM1   c
ITEM2   bla
ITEM2   ds
ITEM3   ccc
ITEM3   ddd
ITEM4   ggg
ITEM4   k
ITEM1   34
ITEM2   435
ITEM1   ooo
ITEM4   kkk
ITEM3   353
ITEM1   sdfs
```

this is the output:

```
[shell] ➤ ./test2.sh
ITEM1   a,b,c,34,ooo,sdfs
ITEM2   bla,ds,435
ITEM3   ccc,ddd,353
ITEM4   ggg,k,kkk
```

Regards

Claudio

Answer (score 0):

For sorted columns. Claudio's script might be better.

```
#!/bin/awk -f

# file: a.awk (add chmod +x)
# start: ./a.awk infile.txt
{
        if (LAST_COL != $1) {
                print LAST_COL " " ITEMS
                ITEMS=$2
                LAST_COL = $1
        } else {
                ITEMS = ITEMS "," $2
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use awk:
You make an array with the first field as index and the contents the concatenation you want.
For each line of the input file see if the first field is already stored in the array "items". Store a new fiels or add a known field with a `,`.
When all lines are procesed, print the array.

```
awk '
   {
      if ($1 in items){
         items[$1]=items[$1] "," $2;
      } else {
         items[$1]=$2;
      }
   }
   END {
      for (key in items) print key "\t" items[key];
   }' input
```

Answer (score 0):

If first word (items) are grouped:

```
awk '{if (item == $1) printf ",%s",$2; else {if (item!="") {printf "\n";} printf "%s",$0;} item=$1 } END{printf "\n";}' input.txt
```